# You're looking at me right now

Tags: riddle

You *might* be holding me in your hands, but the author can't be sure of that because he's not standing right besides you.  What the author can be reasonably sure about is that your day job involves looking at me (or things similar to me) a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a

> **Screen**

Author is pretty sure at our Day job we do keep coming back to Puzzling SE and we are looking at it right now

> through a **screen**

Answer (score 10):

The answer seems to be this.

> a laptop or a mobile phone.

The reason being-
You're looking at me right now.

> Yes Sir, I am.

You might be holding me in your hands, but the author can't be sure of that because he's not standing right besides you.

> He can't be sure about the device on which you are viewing this.

What the author can be reasonably sure about is that your day job involves looking at me (or things similar to me) a lot.

> This, because of the wide assumption that most of us on StackExchange belong to the group whose day job comprises staring at computer screens.

Comment: *Almost.*  I probably should've added a bit more description, because this is technically correct.